# Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I try to run helm install on my chart I get the following error

```
helm install ../my_chart/
    Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Kubernetes version: 1.14.1
Helm version: 2.16.1

Answer (score 2):

I updated the Kubernetes cluster version to 1.15.5 and helm install started working